# How to assign a function to several buttons at the same time? Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm designing my first basic interface in Python 3.8 (using the tkinter module), and I want that instead of **repeating the bound function for each button**, I can make all the buttons take that function (in this case, `command=self.windows`) without having to be repeating the code many times. This is possible? Thank you very much because I am a newbie at this and I am just getting started. Then I leave the code that I have so far, to see how I can improve it. Thanks.

```py
def creator(self):
    lst = []
    arg1, arg2, = 0, 1,
    for i in range(10):   
        btn = Button(self, text='buttons')#
              #command=lambda: self.windows(
              #lambda top1: Class1(top1, i, arg1, arg2, path),
              #lambda top2: Class2(top2, i, arg1, arg2, path),
              #lambda top3: Class3(top3, i, arg1, arg2, path)))
        lst.append(btn)
    
    lst[0].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 0, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 0, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 0, arg1, arg2, path)))
    
    lst[1].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 1, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 1, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 1, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[2].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 2, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 2, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 2, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[3].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 3, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 3, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 3, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[4].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 4, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 4, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 4, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[5].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 5, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 5, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 5, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[6].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 6, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 6, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 6, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[7].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 7, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 7, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 7, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[8].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 8, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 8, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 8, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[9].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 9, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 9, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 9, arg1, arg2, path)))
```

**Example of the minimal and reproducible structure that tries to explain the use of lambdas.**

```
import os   # os.path.join(), os.listdir()
import sys  # sys.argv
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Array(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path, *args):
        super().__init__(master, *args) 
        
        self.image = Image.open(path)
        self.img_copy = self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = tk.Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self, event):
        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()//2))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)


class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, folder, *args):
        super().__init__(master, *args)      
        self.folder = folder
        
        #self.path_lst = ['11.png','22.png','33.png','44.png']
        self.path_lst = [os.path.join(self.folder, name) for name in os.listdir(self.folder) if name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.gif'))]
        print(self.path_lst )
        
        self._frame_1 = None
        self._frame_2 = None
        self._open_1 = False
        self._open_2 = False
        
        index_1 = 0
        index_2 = 2
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text='pack 1',
                      command=lambda:self.windows(lambda top:ShowImage(top, index_1, index_2, self.path_lst),
                                                  lambda top2:ShowImage2(top2, index_1, index_2, self.path_lst)))
        self.button1.pack()
 
    def windows(self, var_1, var_2):
        if not self._open_1:
            self.top1 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.top1.geometry('200x200')
                                
        container = var_1(self.top1)

        if self._frame_1 is not None:  
            self._frame_1.destroy()
            
        self._frame_1 = container
        self._frame_1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self._open_1 = True

        self.top1.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.closed(1))
    

        if not self._open_2:
            self.top2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.top2.geometry('200x200')
                                
        container2 = var_2(self.top2)

        if self._frame_2 is not None:  
            self._frame_2.destroy()
            
        self._frame_2 = container2
        self._frame_2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self._open_2 = True

        self.top2.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.closed(2))
    

    def closed(self, number):
        if number == 1:
            self.top1.destroy()
            self._open_1 = False
        if number == 2:
            self.top2.destroy()
            self._open_2 = False


class ShowImage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, index_1, index_2, path_lst, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_1:
            self.img = Array(self, path_lst[index_1])
            self.img.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_2:
            self.img2 = Array(self, path_lst[index_2])
            self.img2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='news')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


class ShowImage2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, index_1, index_2, path_lst, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_1:
            self.img = Array(self, path_lst[index_1])
            self.img.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')
        
        if len(path_lst) > index_2:
            self.img2 = Array(self, path_lst[index_2])
            self.img2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='news')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

# --- main ---

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    print('if:', folder, len(folder))
else:
    folder = os.getcwd()  # c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\proyect

root = tk.Tk()
frm = Interface(root, folder)
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is `Class1`, `Class2`, and `Class3` actual classes? It's highly unusual to have a button directly instantiate a class. Also, it looks like the only difference between the three classes is the second argument. Have you considered simply creating a single function that take that number as a parameter and then instantiates the class? That seems to be the most obvious solution, and it's not clear if you've rejected that solution for some reason.

Comment: @BryanOakley If they are real classes, they inherit from ```Frame``` and each instance is a child of ```Toplevel```, the arguments they receive are a list of images and their indexes. I am a newbie, but I have tried to fix the problem so as not to repeat the code, but I cannot, **I would really appreciate if you could guide me in this part. Thanks**

Comment: In your `creator` function, you don't define `top1`, `top2`, `top3`, or `path`. Also, the `self.windows` function in the top block of code takes different arguments than the `self.window` in the bottom part of code.